# SQL Database Restore

Tags: sql, backup, restore

We are using SQL 2019.  I wanted to create a Production database from my Dev database.   So I took a full backup of the Dev database and restored it as Production - that part completed OK.   But after it completed, I noticed that my Dev database is inaccessible and says (Restoring...).   Why is this?   I did not specifically ask to restore the Dev database.   Also, it has been in this Restoring... state for some time now, a few hours, much longer than it took to create the Prod database.   How can I get back to normal status?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most obvious answer, of course, but you may need to run the database engine or GUI again, whichever is running you into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get back to normal status, but my larger question is "Why did this happen in the first place?"   I did not intend to restore my Dev database, only the Production database.   Did I miss a restore setting?  or is this just normal SQL Server behavior?

Comment: You should update your question with this new question instead of posting it as an answer. You are more likely to get the feedback you seek that way.